# What happens inside a point lamp

Tags: lighting

So point lamps can be scaled such that they completely envelop an object. How does a point lamp emit light inside itself?

Comment: what do you mean by "inside itself"? Could you be more precise?

Comment: Well a point lamp has a certain radius what if objects are inside that radius

Comment: it will be lit like the other objects

Comment: I think increasing the radius is useful when you need to put a light object into a mesh object so that the light can go beyond the mesh limits

Answer (score 3):

The radius setting is used for *shadows* cast by illuminated objects and also to evenly *distribute* the wattage of the light in the radius volume.  Radius is used to calculate the angle and projection for the edge of the shadow from the light for objects on the shadow side of other objects.

[image]

Therefore an object that is inside the light radius will cast less or no shadow depending on % volume of object inside the radius.

[image]